# How to find out if in nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 3
        )

)
```

I want to basically check if a value is in this array.  So if country_id = 1, then it's true, etc.

any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$found = false;
foreach ($your_array as $key => $element) {
   if (isset($element['country_id']) && ($element['country_id'] == 1)) {
       $found = $key;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Might be an issue when `$key == 0`.

Comment: Only if you do `if (!$found)`. Doing `if ($found !== FALSE)` will handle that.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a single magic function in PHP that will make this a simple solution, you could use something like array_map to accomplish this but you will probably be better off just iterating through the entire array and store the entries that match your criteria.